# Open xaml window, lock Visual Studio UI

Tags: vsix

I am building a Visual Studio Extension (2012 VSIX)
What I want to do is:

Open a XAML Window, bring it to the front. And "lock" Visual Studio, so you have to close the window before you can accomplish something els.

For example when you are right clicking on a project and selects "Add new Item", you have to close the "Add new item window" before you can do anything els.

I did try something simple with just fetching a click event,

```
var window = new XamlWindow();
window.Show();
```

Opened the window, but couldnt find any settings for what I want. (Lock Visual studio untils you close the window again) 
What should I do to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try [`window.ShowDialog()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx).